# Autodesk Forge Viewer fit to view portrait/landscape

Tags: mobile, orientation, autodesk, viewer, forge

I have a Forge viewer app where I want the camera to fit the model bounding box if the orientation on mobile devices changes.

I load the model and set the camera to a specific position in the `Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT` event. Then I fit the model with `viewer.fitToView()`. That works.
In the `Autodesk.Viewing.VIEWER_RESIZE_EVENT`, which is also fired if the orientation of the screen changes,  I run `viewer.fitToView()` again but the camera doesn't change.

The function doesn't seem to even run, but there is also no error message. If I zoom out of the model before changing the orientation the camera distance doesn't change although it should.

Maybe I use the wrong approach here but I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I have locked panning of the camera:

```
viewer.navigation.setLockSettings({"orbit":true, "zoom":true})
viewer.navigation.setIsLocked(true)
```

With those settings fitToView doesn't work. I now disable locking before fitting.